# Squeezed ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting

When I execute the following,

```
ListContourPlot[{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
   0}}]
```

the output is not symmetric in two directions, which can be seen from the following:

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You could try `ListContourPlot[{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
   0}}, InterpolationOrder -> n]`, where`n` takes on different values. Try `n=3`.

Answer (score 4):

You can add an explicit `InterpolationOrder` directive. The default is no interpolation (i.e. `InterpolationOrder -> None`).

With:

```
list = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

In your case:

```
ListContourPlot[list, InterpolationOrder -> #] & /@ Range[1, 3]
```

[image: contour plots with different interpolation orders. Results are now symmetrical, but interpolation order 1 is jagged; order 2 and 3 are both smoother and similar]